# How to exit (kill) the command cp

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cp

I have this question: creating an at job that copies all files in your home directory to `/var/tmp` within half an hour. You may want to create a sub-directory in `/var/tmp`. A message will appear to indicate that the copying task is successfully done and I try to solve like this :

```
cp * /var/tmp/ | (try to kill cp )| at now + 30 minute
```

but I am steel I didn't find command that kill cp?

the question in book and i try to solve it . what i understand that copy all file in home to /var/tmp and if the copy file encroach 30 within half an hour then i should stop it copy

Comment: First of all `cp * /var/tmp/` launched in your home directory will NOT recursively copy all files. Assuming, for example, that you have a "Music" directory in your home directory, no files from that directory will be copied. Then, it is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to copy files for 30 minutes then kill `cp` or do you want to launch `cp` every 30 minutes ? I am really trying to understand :-(

Comment: the question in book and i try to solve it . what i understand that copy all file in home to /var/tmp and if the copy file encroach 30  within half an hour then i should stop it copy

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the exact wording from the book for that task?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to re-invent the [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation) command

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script, assuming you only have one `cp` command in the script, you could use `$$` which returns the PID of the shell script, so `ps -ef | grep $$` will return your script as well as the `cp` command, so `ps -ef | grep -E "$$.*cp` will return the PID of the `cp` command, then you simply do `kill -15 <pid>`. Here is a script that does it all, do NOT put "cp" in the name.

```
#!/bin/sh


cp -r .* /var/tmp/ &

#sleep 30 minutes then kill cp
sleep 1800 && kill -15 $(ps -ef | grep -E "$$.*cp " | awk '{print $2}') || echo "copy completed as kill failed"
```

This script you can schedule with `at` or `cron`.

You probably would like to do the following if you have to use `at` to kill the script, name this one `myScript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $$ > /tmp/myPID    
cp -r .* /var/tmp/
rm /tmp/myPID
```

A second script named `killerQueen.sh` for `at` to kill the process after 30 minutes:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f /tmp/myPID]; then 
  kill -15 $(cat /tmp/myPID)
  echo "Copy not complete." > /tmp/message$$
else
  echo "Copy successful." > /tmp/message$$
fi
```

run the following:

```
$ myScript.sh&
Job 1
$ at -f ./killerQueen.sh now + 30 minute
```

This second example is safer, because we kill the script that performs the copy, if it is still running, else we create a file named `/tmp/message<pid_of_killerQueen>` with the text "copy succeeded".

EDIT, after reading `man at` and your comment:

```
cp -r * /var/tmp& echo "kill -15 \$(ps -ef | grep \"$$.*cp \" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')" | at now + 1 second
```

Comment: it show a Messages that no such process i write like this : cp -r * /var/tmp & kill -15 $(ps -ef | grep -E "$$.*cp " | awk '{print $2}') | at now + 30 minute  || echo "copy completed as kill failed" its correct ?

Comment: Sorry. I do not use `at` that much and got a bit confused by your question ... of course, you want to `echo` the command to `at`, d'oh. And then, of course, you enter the beautiful world of escaping ...

Comment: it steel tell me that Syntax error.last token seen .s garbled time =( but it did the copy =( and i am so happy that you help me =)

Answer (score 0):

Firs I would suggest you to use the `rsync` command to preserve unnecessary copy of unchanged files. Second you could push the `rsync` process into the *background* by using the command `nohup`. Then you can `kill` the process, using the PID of the job most recently placed into the background `!$` (issued by the `nohup` command) `at` certain time:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
nohup rsync -arqvzh --ignore-errors "$HOME"/* "/var/tmp/" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo "kill -9 $!" | at now +30 minutes -M > /dev/null 2>&1
```

References:

- ["kill <PID>" not really killing the process, why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59811/kill-pid-not-really-killing-the-process-why) | [How do I kill processes in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104903/how-do-i-kill-processes-in-ubuntu)
- [How to run nohup and write its pid file in a single bash statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254155/how-to-run-nohup-and-write-its-pid-file-in-a-single-bash-statement)
- [How do I use the nohup command without getting nohup.out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out)
- [How to let 'cp' command don't fire an error when source file does not exist?](https://serverfault.com/questions/153875/how-to-let-cp-command-dont-fire-an-error-when-source-file-does-not-exist)
- [Run command `at` 5 seconds from now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905886/run-command-at-5-seconds-from-now)
- [GNU - Bash Reference Manual:Shell Parameters:Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters)

---

Alternatively you could use the [`timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation) command - as [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) have [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982816/how-to-exit-kill-the-command-cp/983071#comment1580728_982816) - in this way:

```
timeout 1800 rsync -arqvzh --ignore-errors "$HOME"/* "/var/tmp/" &
```

Where:

- 1800 is the duration of the *timeout* in seconds.
- `&` will push the process into the background, thus you could use the current shell.