# Can't Kill VLC until Restart

Tags: video, vlc, kill, killall

Sometimes, after I play some videos  with VLC Media Player, it stops working and I can't use it or kill it. The icon still appears in the system tray. When I click it and press "Quit," nothing happens. I tried `killall vlc` and I also found the PID and used `sudo kill` but VLC will never quit! Isn't `kill` supposed to...kill the program?

When I kill it with the command line, it acts as if it killed it (no output). I am able to still enter `killall vlc` or `kill` by PID as many times as I want but vlc stays there.

Why isn't it stoping? The only way to quit VLC is to restart my computer, but I don't want to do that.

Why is this happening? Is it a bug in VLC or is there a reason it happened?

Also, is there a way to prevent this in the future, like maybe a config file or something?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/59811/kill-pid-not-really-killing-the-process-why

Comment: have you tried using the -9 flag when killing by process ID? Did you look in the vlc logs? (or any logs?) If you want to know why vlc is malfunctioning you are going to have to provide a bit more info about the scenario... Have you tried a vlc forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Stop, Continue, End, and Kill programs from the System Monitor. If VLC appears in it, you can right-click on the process and choose to kill it from there.

Comment: This works, thanks. I did not accept this answer because I also would like to know why it happened and how to prevent it in the future.

Comment: @AlexFullinator You have multiple questions but your main one - "Can't Kill VLC until Restart" - has been fully answered here. You may want to post an additional question by itself, perhaps referencing this one, but indeed you should accept it.